# Starting build modifier from one end

Tags: build-modifier

I have a cube and have applied the Build Modifier on it. Is there any way to start the build from one end and gradually build it fully to the other end?

Answer (score 1):

You need to sort the vertices:

- In *Edit* mode, select the vertex that you want to choose as the first one, then <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor To Selected*.

[image]

- Select all, go in the *Mesh* menu > *Sort Elements > Cursor Distance*.

[image]

- In the *Operator* box, click on *Face*. Now it should work. If you want to check the vertices numbers, go in the *Preferences > Interface > Display > enable Developer Extras*. Then in the 3D view > *Viewport Overlays > Developer*, enable *Indices*.

[image]